# c# share on wall after liking application

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, sdk

when I've got an facebook application, there is an Like button, near the name of app. I would like to post on someone wall after clicking the like button (in this moment the page is reloaded and content is changing from page for not like users to page for like users), using c# facebook sdk for mvc 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dependant upon the URL you specify in the like button  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

You should ensure that the URL you specified can be linted by https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint and that the og: tags are correct.